# WPF, MVVM: How to handle heavy(slow) initialization

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm, constructor, initialization

In my viewmodels, I generally need to fetch data from database or check some ports and connections to access some hardware which takes about 3-10 seconds.

If I put that initialization to my VM constructor, then the UI will freeze. I don't want that ofcourse. I can spawn a new thread and do initialization there but that brings implementation and synchronization overhead always as I need to do this in many VM's. Such a VM ctor would look like that:

```
public PrinterConfigurationVM()
{
    ScanPrintersOnCOM(); // Scans COM ports and identifies if it is a printer, slow
    ScanPrintersOnUSB(); // Scans USB printers, fast
    FetchPrinterConfigurations(); // Access to db, not so slow
}
```

Is there already a simple solution to that(pattern or some lib)? What is your suggestion?

System: .NET 4.0, WPF, MVVM Light

Comment: Why don't you have a class that all your VMs can access which scans for Printers once on a background thread, and includes a method that can be called to rescan if needed?

Comment: 3-10 seconds is not terrible, you could disable the UI, display a spinner, maybe a progressbar if you can estimate the time, and launch one thread to create all the VMs.

Comment: @Rachel, As I mentioned, I need this behavior in many VM's for many resources. I can implement what you suggested but I want to know if there is an easier way already.

Comment: @Pragmateek, There are many resources that takes that much time to initialize. So if you multiply that number by say 5, it goes up to a minute, or I need initialize them in parallel in a background thread(brings much complexity).

Comment: @Mert Background threads really aren't that complex these days. I'd suggest taking a look at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). It's simple and easy to use, without much extra code (For example, `Task.Factory.StartNew(LoadPrinters);` to call your `LoadPrinters()` method on a background thread)

Comment: Ok but don't forget that letting the user plays with the model while you are updating it can have unwanted side effects, so you may have to write a lot of plumbing to ensure synchronization. Depends on your situation but if the user can wait simpler is better :)

Comment: @Rachel: launching threads has always been an easy task, synchronizing them correctly is still a complex one ;)

Comment: @Pragmateek I guess I just don't see the problem with this code sample :) Create an `ObservableCollection<Printer>`, search for printers on a separate thread, fill your collection on the main thread with the search results, and bind UI to the collection. It will automatically update the UI when the collection gets new items since it triggers a `CollectionChanged` event, the long-running part will execute on the background thread to avoid locking the UI, and the collection can be locked and updated on the main thread so the threads don't trip over each other trying to update it at the same time

Comment: Thanks, I will implement a base class to handle background loading and will insert loaded objects into ObservableCollection<>. I hope the collection won't blow up during insertion from background thread .)

Comment: @Rachel: this is why I requested more info: for the simple use-case you describe this is perfect but imagine you start updating the UI and let the user interact with it: it selects printer 2 in list, but when you update the list another printer could be inserted and selected, so in fact printer 3 is chosen and you end up sending your 1000 pages document on the color printer, so you need to carefully control the interactions. But I may be too paranoiac... ;) Note that you can enhance granularity by only locking with a spinner one single list in the UI, refresh it, then lock another...

Comment: So if the user can (it depends on the requirements) wait 1 minute just lock everything and update safely: 5 minutes of development and you can go to more interesting/high-value requirements. :)

Comment: @Pragmateek Well if you're binding to a collection of `Printers` that may be getting updated as you select one, I'd highly recommend you bind the `SelectedItem` instead of the `SelectedIndex` so that sort of problem doesn't occur :) Personally I'd create a single class to manage unlikely-to-change system resources (like Printers), and provide a `Rescan()` or `Refresh()` method if needed. You could load that in the background on startup, and if the user wants to refresh the list after the application has started up, then they should be OK waiting a few seconds after clicking the Refresh button.

Comment: Yep, as suggested I will lock controls and maybe spawn Minesweeper. I think it is the most pragmatic .)

Comment: @Mert: I agree, tough it's hard to stay pragmatic when you're a geek. :)